# toJSON method not getting called when in nested array

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, class, types

I'm currently working on a project in typescript and using the methods toJSON and fromJSON to properly parse my objects.

I'm having a strange issue when calling JSON.stringify() on one of my classes, where it doesn't call the toJSON methods of the nested parameters.

Here is a summary of my classes:

```
class TFClass {
   ...

   toJSON(): ITFSerialized {
      console.log('not printing')
      ...
   }

}

class ConfigClass {
   transfer_functions: TFClass[];
   ...
   toJSON(): IConfigSerialized {
      return Object.assign({}, this, {
         transfer_functions: this.transfer_functions,
      });
   }

}
```

When I call `JSON.stringify(<ConfigClass>obj)` the transfer_functions variable is of type `TFClass[]` and so it doesn't enter the TFClass toJSON method.

However say transfer_functions was of type TFClass (not an array), then it's able to enter the respective toJSON method.

Are there any changes I can make to make it functional ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to include the class reviver as the second argument to the JSON.parse function. This ensures that the toJSON method properly gets called.

Comment: While I think I understand what you mean here (ensuring that parsed objects become `TFClass`, so they will have `toJSON()` available when stringified *again*?), this detail is not described in the question.

Comment: I don't understand the solution. What function needs to be implemented, can you give an example?

Comment: yeah noidea what this solution means either